# C++ Trouble doing simple addition in while() loop

Tags: c++

Hopefully someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm reading up to a specific point on each line within a text file and then trying to add that value to the value on the next line and continue doing so until the end of the file/loop. But at the moment, it will only add the values from the first two lines and not...

123 + 456 + 789 = totalPayroll.

My code is as follows:

```
inStream.open("staffMembers.txt");

while(getline(inStream.ignore(256, '$'), line))
{
    totalPayroll = stoi(line) + stoi(line);
}

inStream.close();

cout << "$" << totalPayroll << endl;
```

My text file is formatted as follows:

```
1 | Person One | $123
2 | Person Two | $456
3 | Person Three | $789
```

Comment: Did you mean `totalPayroll += stoi(line);`?

Comment: That it exactly what I wanted. Thank you! Would you mind explaining what += means exactly in an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: `a+=b` is equivalent of `a = a+ b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your loop, you're reassigning `totalPayroll` the value of `stoi(line) + stoi(line)` for every line, so it ends up finally being 2*789.

You need to keep a continuous sum:

```
totalPayroll = totalPayroll + stoi(line);
```

This also has a short form using a compound assignment operator, which does the same thing:

```
totalPayroll += stoi(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

As chris mentioned in his comment, `totalPayroll += stoi(line);` should solve your problem.

The C++ operator `+=` is a shorthand way of writing `totalPayroll = totalPayroll + stoi(line);`. It adds the value given on the righthand side of the operator to the current value of the variable.

Comment: why do you post an answer when someone has already pointed it out in the comments?? just for points? :)

Comment: @Bill, I should have figured that would be it from the beginning and went straight for an answer. As it is, I posted one just before j883376. It's entirely possible mine wasn't even noticed.

Comment: I was elaborating on what chris pointed out in his comment, since cvandal was unsure what += meant. Since chris made an answer himself a couple seconds before I hit submit, he got upvoted accordingly